# How to fix forms authentication with 51degrees detection library?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, 51degrees

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC app that uses custom forms-based authentication, by creating a **FormsAuthenticationTicket** and writing the auth cookie per the example at [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Now, when I add a reference to the 51degrees mobile device detection framework, I'm stuck in an auth loop, with **context.Request.IsAuthenticated** permanently reporting **false**.

I've tracked it down to the fact that **context.Request.Browser.Cookies** is now also reporting **false**, which explains why my auth cookie isn't having any effect. But what would cause the library to think my desktop browser (Chrome in this case, if that makes any difference) suddenly didn't support cookies? Bug in the detection library? Misconfiguration or code error on my end? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to 51degrees V3 using nuget and ran into the same problem.

You are correct - `context.Request.Browser.Cookies` is false so the authentication cookie doesn't get set AND even if one is there it doesn't get read. I tried manually setting it using `FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie()` followed by a `Response.Cookies.Add()` and it still didn't work.

I think it's a bug in the 51degrees library. But I do have a solution.

According to MSDN, `FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported` relies on `FormsAuthentication.CookieMode` property, which relies on the `<forms cookieless="">` attribute.

By default, if the `<form>` `cookieless` property is not set, it defaults to `UseDeviceProfile`, which 51degrees reports `false` for so forms authentication will not look at or set the cookie.

Manually setting `<form cookieless="UseCookies">` forces `FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported` to be true, so the auth cookie is set and read.

I tried that and authentication works again.

Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiessupported(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.cookiessupported%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

--Edit--: The `<sessionState>` system.web element also has a `cookieless` attribute. It's set to `UseCookies` by default so that's why session state using a session cookie still works.
Source: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)